# PostgreSQL left join with alias in a loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to iterate over a table's records and make a left join with them in a stored procedure?
Something like this:

```
FOR r IN SELECT tablename FROM tablewithtablenames ORDER BY tablename ASC
LOOP


    INSERT INTO temp_Results 
    SELECT 
         temp_ids.Key as Key, 
         loggedvalue.pk_timestamp,
         FROM 
            (temp_idS AS temp_ids
                  LEFT JOIN 
                        quote_ident(r.tablename) AS loggedvalue 
                            ON temp_ids.Key = loggedvalue.pk_fk_id);
  END LOOP;
```

Unfortunately i get the following error message when i want to execute the stored procedure. (Function creation was successful.)

Error message:

> ERROR:  column loggedvalue.pk_fk_id does not exist LINE 29:
>   ON temp_ids.Key = "loggedvalue...

I have the feeling that i convert the record in a wrong way maybe because when i manually replaced the quote_ident(r.tablename) to the name of the table that i know the *r* contains it was fine, also i traced out the r.tablename in the loop and it was correct also.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that

Comment: Why? I would specifically avoid dynamic sql because afaik the optimizer can not optimize them.
 Source: (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-implementation.html)

"you can construct dynamic commands using the PL/pgSQL EXECUTE statement — at the price of performing new parse analysis and constructing a new execution plan on every execution."

Comment: You simply can not use a variable (and a field of a record is also a variable) as a table name (or an identifier in general). Of course the optimizer can optimize dynamic SQL - but the plans are not cached as with other queries inside a stored function.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just wish i knew that you cant use the table name as a variable before

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because the misunderstanding was cleared in comments and will barely serve other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name pointed out i should have use dynamic sql because in plpgsql you can not use a variable as a table name so i eliminated the loop and i used a *union all*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getaffectedtables(
OUT tableNames TEXT)
as $$
BEGIN
    SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ' UNION ALL ' FROM string_agg('','SELECT * FROM "' || "tablename" || '" UNION ALL ')) 
    INTO tableNames 
    FROM exampleTable;

END;$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then i used dynamic execute:

```
DECLARE
    affectednames TEXT; 
BEGIN
    affectednames := getaffectedtables();

   EXECUTE '
    SELECT 
         temp_ids.Key as Key, 
         loggedvalue.pk_timestamp,
         FROM 
            (temp_idS AS temp_ids
                  LEFT JOIN 
                        ('|| affectednames ||') AS loggedvalue 
                            ON temp_ids.Key = loggedvalue.pk_fk_id);';
```